# Replacing errors with custom messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

My program is about image treatment, and it asks the user when run to open an image. But if the user closes the window without selecting any image, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "E:\Projet Complet\Test 2.py", line 255, in <module>
    Ima1=Image.open(a)
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2317, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm trying to replace that error with a custom message like `"You didn't choose any image"` in an opened message box. I know how to open the message box, but I don't know how to replace the error message with it.
I tried doing this:

```
main.withdraw()
try:
    a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    main.deiconify()
except AttributeError:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Image Error", "You didn't choose any image.")
    sys.exit()
```

But it gives me the above error.
Here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED, messagebox as tkMessageBox
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import PIL
from collections import Counter
from random import randint
import random
import PIL.ImageOps


def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def get_pixel(pixels, x, y):
    try:
        return pixels[x, y]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def get_neighbors(pixels, x, y):
    neighbors = list()
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x - 1, y + 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y - 1))
    neighbors.append(get_pixel(pixels, x + 1, y + 1))
    return neighbors


def filter_art(pixels, size):
    indexes = dict()
    for x in range(size[0]):
        for y in range(size[1]):
            color = get_pixel(pixels, x, y)
            neighbors = get_neighbors(pixels, x, y)
            new_color = Counter(neighbors).most_common()[0][0]
            if new_color is not None:
                indexes[x, y] = new_color
    for x, y in indexes:
        pixels[x, y] = indexes[x, y]


def pop_art(path_orig, path_mod, coef):

    s=[]
    for i in range(9):

        r=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        g=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
        b=(randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))

        image_orig = Image.open(path_orig)
        size = image_orig.size
        image_mod = Image.new("RGB",(size[0],size[1]))
        pixels_orig = image_orig.load()
        pixels_mod = image_mod.load()
        for x in range(size[0]):
            for y in range(size[1]):
                p = pixels_orig[x, y]
                if isinstance(p, int):
                    rgb = (p,p,p)
                elif isinstance(p, tuple) and len(p) in (3, 4):
                    rgb = p[:3]
                else:
                    raise TypeError('Unknown pallete')
                average_color = sum(rgb) / 3
                if average_color <= 85:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = r
                elif 85 < average_color <= 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = g
                elif average_color > 170:
                    pixels_mod[x, y] = b
        for _ in range(coef):
            filter_art(pixels_mod, size)
        image_mod.save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result'+str(i)+'.png')
        Img=[None]*9
    for i in range(9):
        Img[i]=Image.open(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Modified Images\\result"+str(i)+".png")
        basewidth = int(Img[i].size[1]/3)
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(Img[i].size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(Img[i].size[1]) * float(wpercent )))
        Img[i] = Img[i].resize((basewidth , hsize ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Img[i].save(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')


    Img1=[None]*9
    pixels1=[None]*9
    Imaz=Image.new("RGB",(basewidth*3,hsize*3))
    pixels=Imaz.load()
    for i in range(9):
        Img1[i]=Image.open(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')
        pixels1[i]=Img1[i].load()


    for x in range(0,basewidth):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[0][x,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[1][x,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[2][x,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth,basewidth*2):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[3][x-basewidth,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[4][x-basewidth,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[5][x-basewidth,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth*2,basewidth*3):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[6][x-basewidth*2,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[7][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[8][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize*2]
    Imaz = Imaz.resize((size[0] , size[1] ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    Imaz.save(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")


def usepop():
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\traitement.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    I2.update_idletasks()
    pop_art(a, None, coef=4)
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def change_contrast(level):

    img = Image.open(a)
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if type(color) == int:
                color=(color,color,color)
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                new_color = new_color[0]
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
            elif type(color) != int:
                new_color = tuple(int(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
                img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)
    return img

def use_contrast():
    result = change_contrast(S2.get())
    result.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

def recherche_contours():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2 = Ima2.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
    image = Ima2
    if image.mode == 'RGBA':
        r,g,b,a = image.split()
        rgb_image = Image.merge('RGB', (r,g,b))

        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(rgb_image)

        r2,g2,b2 = inverted_image.split()

        final_transparent_image = Image.merge('RGBA', (r2,g2,b2,a))

        final_transparent_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")

    else:
        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
        inverted_image.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)

main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
try:
    a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    main.deiconify()
except AttributeError:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Resolution Error", "The image is too big, please select a smaller one.")
    sys.exit()


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("Test2.py"))

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")
try:
    Ima1=Image.open(a)
    z=Ima1.size
    nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    nuxy=nux.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
    nux.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")


    main.withdraw()
    a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
except AttributeError:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Image Error", "You didn't choose any image.")
    sys.exit()
main.deiconify()

if z>(400,400):
    main.withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Resolution Error", "The image is too big, please select a smaller one.")
    sys.exit()

elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan =3)
    imt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan =4)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=0)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=1)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=7)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=6)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = usepop, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=3)
    S2 = Scale(main, from_=-258, to=258, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S2.grid(row=2, column=4)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Contraste", command = use_contrast, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=4)
    B5 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Trouver Contours", command = recherche_contours, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B5.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=1, column=5)

    s=S1.get()
    s2=S2.get()




main.mainloop()
```

EDIT1:
I applied the answer from  @Juan T, and it did display the message, but it doesn't close the window even though I initiated `sys.exit()` 
[image: bug]

EDIT2: 
    I found how to fix it all I had to do was add `main.destroy()` before `sys.exit()`

EDIT3:
Now when I run the code, I select the image, and it prompts me again for the image. I want it to prompt it once.

EDIT4: I fixed it, the problem was I had an old snippet hidden in the code that was causing the problem, all fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you put the `try` before. So, instead of:

```
Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
...
nux.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")


main.withdraw()
try:
    a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
except AttributeError:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Image Error", "You didn't choose any image.")
    sys.exit()
main.deiconify()
```

Consider:

```
try:
    Ima1=Image.open(a)
    z=Ima1.size
    ...
    nux.save(""+dir_path+"\\Requirements\\Blank.png")

    main.withdraw()

    a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
except AttributeError:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Image Error", "You didn't choose any image.")
    sys.exit()
main.deiconify()
```

Comment: I used and it partially worked. Now it displays the message, but it doesn't quit the window I had previously opened. (a screenshot was added to the post)

Comment: I found how to fix it all I had to do was add `main.destroy()` before `sys.exit()`